# Providing Smart-Group Specific Price Sets

Tags: civievent

I see there is an extension that indicates it will allow group-specific price sets:
https://github.com/zengenuity/civicrm_groupprice

I'm running civi 5.20 on Joomla, and when I activate this extension and edit a Price set, I don't see the option to limit a Price Set to a group.

Is anyone using this extension successfully? I see is is built for civiCRM v4.4, so I'll hazard a guess it doesn't work with 5.20 .. but I wonder, what are people doing instead, to provide group-specific pricing?

My requirement is that I need to provide Member and Non-Member pricing for an event with several options (like Opening Night + Conf and Conference Only), and Members and non-members pay different amounts... How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [CiviDiscount](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount) which offers options for eg auto-discounts for people logged in or using a checksum who are Members